# Find missing values between text files using VBScript

Tags: vbscript, file-processing

## EDIT 2

Just to make it clear - this question is not asking for "DA CODEZ", just  an idea as to possible approaches in VBScript. It's not my weapon of choice, and if I needed to do this on a un*x box then I wouldn't be bothering anyone with this...

---

I have two text files. **File A** contains a list of keys:

```
00001 13756 000.816.000 BE2B
00001 13756 000.816.000 BR1B
00002 16139 000.816.000 BR1B
00001 10003 000.816.000 CH1C
00001 10003 000.816.000 CH3D
00001 13756 000.816.000 CZ1B
....
....
```

**File B**, tab separated, contains two columns the keys, and a UUID:

```
00003 16966 001.001.023 2300    a3af3b1d-ea04-4948-ba25-59b36ae364ae
00001 12119 001.001.023 CZ1B    e6efe825-0759-48b0-89b9-05bbe5d49625
00002 16966 001.001.023 BR1B    d3a1d62b-a0d5-43c3-ba49-a219de5f32a5
00001 12119 001.001.023 BR1B    5d74af27-ed4b-4f90-8229-90b6d807515b
00001 10009 001.001.024 BR1B    590409cc-496a-49eb-885c-9bbc51863363
00002 24550 001.001.024 2100    46ecea5d-f8f5-4df9-92cf-0b73f6c81adc
00001 12119 001.001.024 CZ1B    e415ce6f-7394-4a66-a7f8-f76487e78086
00002 16966 001.001.024 CZ1B    c591a726-4d71-4f61-adfd-63310d21d397
....
....
```

I need to extract, using plain VBScript, the UUIDs for those entries in **File B** which have no matching entry in **File A**. (I need to optimise for speed, if that's an important criteria.) The result should be a file of orphaned UUID codes.

If this isn't easy/possible, that's also an answer - I can do it in the db we're using but the performance is woefully inadequate. Just been blown away by how much faster VBScript was than db solution for a previous processing task.

## EDIT

Someone's suggested using some sort of ADO library, after converting the file to CSV, which I'm looking into.

Comment: What have you tried do you have some code you can share?, as you are probably well aware [so] is not *code* for "GIV ME DA CODEZ!". If not see [ask] and providing a [mcve].

Comment: What kind of volumes are we talking about here?, if the database can't handle it I doubt VBScript is the way to go.

Comment: No indeed Lankymart. I will endeavour so to do, shortly once I've tried to pick apart ADO stuff.

Comment: About 400 files. Mode, about 1k lines, max about 2.5m lines.

Comment: Wow, not a job I would entrust to VBScript, what is your database architecture?

Comment: FileMaker ;-) Are we getting the picture now.

Comment: Crystal clear @dycey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the fastest way to do it is just to ask the OS to do it

```
Dim orphan
    orphan = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec( _ 
        "findstr /g:keys.txt /v uuids.txt" _ 
    ).StdOut.ReadAll()

    WScript.Echo orphan
```

That is, use `findstr` to check the `uuids.txt` file for lines that do not match any of the lines in the `keys.txt` file

Comment: Thanks @MCND Just so you know - this shaved a 1h49min process to less than 2 mins ;-) I think that's a 60x gain ;-) Much appreciated. It's always wkward when you're not on familiar turf, and Windows scripting is quite unfamiliar to me. One small point - there's an answer worth a read for the [issues with Findstr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844868/what-are-the-undocumented-features-and-limitations-of-the-windows-findstr-comman).

Comment: Decent approach. Was VBScript always a requirement then @Dycey or could you just as easily do this from the command line or batch file?

Comment: The server environment is locked down. It is however possible to run a VBScript from within a FileMaker schedule. It's awkward and uncomfortable, and entirely unfamiliar. The whole thing is maneuvering an RV down a side-alley backwards in a blindfold, listening to thrash metal all the way up to 11. There seems to be no "easily" for this particular job. ;-)